# How to have a const member in all instances of a struct using C (not C++)?

Tags: c, struct

I want to design a struct in C, which is like:

```
typedef struct {
    const int HEADER;
    int data;
} A_STRUCT;
```

I hope all the instances of this struct have the same known const HEADER value, e.g. `0x33`. Basically, I need a member variable which is initialized automatically in each instance of the struct. What is the correct way to do it in C (not C++)? Esp. how to initialize it?

Comment: You have to initialize this data member for each instance of the structure.

Comment: `A_STRUCT x = { 42, -1 };` after that it's illegal to attempt to change `x.HEADER`

Comment: Please make an [mcve], i.e. show the code which you want to write which USES variables of that struct type.

Comment: Why not just *define* a constant for it (e.g. `#define HEADER 0x33` or `enum {HEADER = 0x33};`)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have many `A_STRUCT`, `B_STRUCT`, `C_STRUCT`. Each with different HEADER values.

Comment: You cannot. C has nothing like that.

Comment: OP, you're trying to make C look like C++, in other words, C does not have a facility to do this.

Comment: I see an ambiguity in your question. What do you actually want? A global variable which can be accessed in `A_STRUCT::HEADER` fashion? Or a normal member variable which is initialized automatically in each instance of the struct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "a normal member variable which is initialized automatically in each instance of the struct".

Comment: @stanleyli, It is unclear how many you have, but if you need constants, define them, e.g. `enum { HEADERA = 0x33, HEADERB = 0x43, ...};`, then on declaration initialize `HEADER` (e.g. `A_STRUCT A = { .HEADER = HEADERA };` ). That is one of the cleaner ways to insure you have a constant value.

Comment: Then I'd remove the word `static` from the title. In C++, a static member variable is a single variable, which is in essense global, and it's not copied into instances.

Comment: @stanleyli, in that case, I confirm what several others have also said: C does not have that.  Specifically, it does not offer `struct` members whose values are defined by the struct's definition, or are otherwise automatically enforced to have the same value for every object of that type.

Comment: "*a normal member variable which is **initialized automatically** in each instance of the struct*" not possible in C.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the word `static`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer is invalidated by an edit to the question, removing the objective of a "static member" like in C++. Leaving it here just for reference.

A static member in C++ is essentially a global variable that's scoped in the namespace of the `struct`/`class`. So something like this in C++:

foo.h:

```
struct foo
{
    static int bar;
    int baz;
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
int foo::bar = 0x33;
```

translates roughly to the following in C:

foo.h:

```
struct foo
{
    int baz;
}
extern int foo_bar;
```

foo.c:

```
int foo_bar = 0x33;
```

Also note the keyword `static` has an entirely different meaning in C, it declares the variable with static storage; it becomes inaccessible from other translation units.

Comment: I need it to be in the struct. How to do that?

Comment: `foo_bar` is totally separate variable so how does that answer the OP's question?

Comment: It's the functional equivalent to the C++ solution. Please don't downvote if you don't understand C++. static members are just syntactic sugar for global variables.

Comment: I suspect that OP's question is worded poorly. It seems like what they actually want to have a non-static field, which is initialized automatically.

Comment: OP asked specifically C solution to their problem.

Comment: And this **is** the C solution. If OP wants polymorphism, he should pose a different question

Comment: You are right in that C++ code you've presented translates to a C code with global variable but that doesn't answer OP's question, as he won't be able to get a header from the given struct.

Comment: The edit of the op invalidates this answer. Getting the value from an instance would be impossible with a static member in c++ as well

Comment: What's the `extern` for? In C all (non-C-`static`) globals are extern by default.

Comment: @t0mm13b *OP asked specifically C solution to their problem.* And if the OP asked for function overloading in C?

Comment: @alk for splitting header/implementation at `// [...]`

Comment: Then it might make sense to show this explicitly with your snippets.

Comment: In the C++, you're showing a member of `struct foo`, called `bar` to be directly set, i.e. `foo::bar` in assignment expression. However, in C code that you've shown you have member of `struct foo` called `baz` which, you also set a separate variable `foo_bar`.

Comment: In c++, the static member is declared inside the `struct`, but that only puts it in the struct's "namespace". It still lives outside of any struct instance, just like in the c example. `[namespace]_[identifier]` is a common idiom to replace *real* namespaces in c.